# Last and first name lookup, return a value in that row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Using Excel, I have two separate workbooks with one worksheet in each that has one column for last names and one adjacent column for first names in the same (last then first) order.

I want the second workbook, for each row of names, to look at the first workbook for the same last+first name combo and return a value in a separate column on that row.

---

[ExperienceReport.xlsx]Ad Hoc Report:

```
Columns: A    -  B    -  C

Last -  First - Desired Return

Last -  First - Desired Return
```

---

Current worksheet:

```
Columns: H   -   I     -  X

Last  - First  - Find and return Desired Return for this name

Last  - First  - Find and return Desired Return for this name
```

---

So far, I've come up with the follwing, but I'm getting a #VALUE error on every row:

```
=INDEX('[ExperienceReport.xlsx]Ad Hoc Report'!$A$2:$J$150,MATCH($H5&" "&$I5,'[ExperienceReport.xlsx]Ad Hoc Report'!$A$2:$A$150&'[ExperienceReport.xlsx]Ad Hoc Report'!$B$2:$B$150,0),3)
```

Logically, I can't find the problem as it seems like it's going like this: INDEX(look in the specified array on the first workbook/worksheet for the row where MATCH(the 'last first' combo on this sheet matches the 'last first'combo in the A and B columns on the first workbook/worksheet) and give me the value in the 3rd column of that row.

I tend to do things the difficult way, I know, but if anyone can see a glaring error in my ways, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to make a helper column on both sheets that contains the first and last name and use regular `VLOOKUP()`. But there is also a "hard" way.

`INDEX()` and `MATCH()` can only return a single cell or item. What you have to do is combine your columns into a single array inside your formula like this:

```
=INDEX('[ExperienceReport.xlsx]Ad Hoc Report'!$C$2:$C$150,MATCH(H2&" "&I2,'[ExperienceReport.xlsx]Ad Hoc Report'!$A$2:$A$150&" "&'[ExperienceReport.xlsx]Ad Hoc Report'!$B$2:$B$150,0))
```

Or, more generally:

```
=INDEX([Return range],MATCH(arg1&arg2...,[arg1 range]&[arg2 range]...,0))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with ctrl+shift+enter.

Comment: Turns out I'm an idiot and breezed right over the requirement to enter this as an array formula. My formula was correct but I didn't hold CTRL+SHIFT when I hit ENTER. It's working correctly now, Thank you!